# Flutter - Keeping state alive not working as expected

Tags: flutter

At the bottom is the code that I've simplified to represent my issue. But first, let me provide a little explanation about what I'm facing.

We have here a `PageView` with `TextField`s on each page. On `submit()`, I need it to collect all data from each page, so each `ThePageState` must not be null, so the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.`wantKeepAlive` was overridden and the return value was set to always be `true`.

Unfortunately, what happened was not as expected. Right after editing page X's `TextField`'s value, jump to page Y, and passing the focus from page X's `TextField` to page Y's `TextField`, page X's state is gone, keeping me from getting its `TextField`'s `TextEditingController`'s value.

Where I was wrong? I just want to get the values without having to define all the `TextEditingController`s on the parent `TheScreenState`.

```
class TheScreen extends StatefulWidget{

  Map data;

  TheScreen(this.data);

  @override
  TheScreenState createState() => TheScreenState();
}

class TheScreenState extends State<TheScreen>{

  GlobalKey<ViewPageState> keyX = GlobalKey<ViewPageState>();
  GlobalKey<ViewPageState> keyY = GlobalKey<ViewPageState>();
  PageController controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    PageView pageview = PageView(controller : controller, children : [
      ThePage(keyX, widget.data['X']),
      ThePage(keyY, widget.data['Y'])
    ]);
    ...
  }

  @override
  initState(){
    keyX.currentState?.populate();
    keyY.currentState?.populate();
  }

  Future submit() async{
    Map map = {
      'X' : keyX.currentState?.data;
      'Y' : keyY.currentState?.data;
    };
    Navigator.of(context).pop(map);
  }
}

class ThePage extends StatefulWidget{

  GlobalKey<ThePageState> key;
  Map data;
  TextEditingController tecA = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tecB = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tecC = TextEditingController();

  ThePage(this.key, this.data);

  @override
  ThePageState createState() => ThePageState();
}

class ThePageState extends State<ThePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ThePage>{

  PageController pvc = PageController();

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    TextField tfA = TextField(controller : widget.tecA, ...);
    TextField tfB = TextField(controller : widget.tecB, ...);
    TextField tfC = TextField(controller : widget.tecC, ...);
    ...
  }

  void populate(){
    if(widget.tecA.text.isEmpty) widget.tecA.text = widget.data['A'];
    if(widget.tecB.text.isEmpty) widget.tecB.text = widget.data['B'];
    if(widget.tecC.text.isEmpty) widget.tecC.text = widget.data['C'];
  }

  Map get data => {
    'A' : widget.tecA.text,
    'B' : widget.tecB.text,
    'C' : widget.tecC.text
  };
}
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please do NOT edit the tag information back into the title. The tagging system works very well here, and doesn't need help. People who monitor the flutter tag will see the question without the useless clutter of repeating in the title. For more information, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661).

Comment: @KenWhite thank you but believe me you're making it worse as the question lost it's place on search engine. anyway, agree to disagree. peace

Comment: The Meta SE post says that the site consensus is to not include tags in the title. The tagging system works very well here, and the HTML generated for the page includes that information in the page meta information. SO uses SEO to ensure that tag information is included with searches, so that argument is invalid. If you search Google for your post title followed by "flutter", the question is found. Also, the search is irrelevant to you - you know where the question is, because you wrote it. It would be better to use that space to improve the quality of your post title instead.

Comment: @KenWhite ok got it. thanks. i've actually saw the difference from the search result but let's just keep it as my personal view. i've also previously experienced the moment where the answer i was searching for comes from here and i'm the one who asked it. but let's move on and focus on the discussion about my question instead if there's any. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefilly someone come up with better answer than this. I don't think this is the absolute option. But as for now, it solved my case. I did mine by just retrieving the data directly from `ThePage`s.

From `TheScreenState` class.

```
ThePage? pageX, pageY;
    
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
   pageX = ThePage(widget.data['X']),
   pageY = ThePage(widget.data['Y'])
   ...
}

Future submit() async{

   Map map = {
     'X' : pageX?.data;
     'Y' : pageY?.data;
   };
   Navigator.of(context).pop(map);
}
```

From `ThePage` class.

```
Map get data => {
  'A' : tecA.text,
  'B' : tecB.text,
  'C' : tecC.text
};
```